# Text FIle printing Java Applet not working in windows OS

Tags: java, applet

I am created a java applet for copy a text file content from remote location to local computer. Its working fine and also try to print using dos command(Windows XP). Its not working but its working fine in Ubuntu OS. Can you please help me to improve my code..

Here is my code

```
try {
            String server=this.getParameter("SERVER");
            String filename=this.getParameter("FILENAME");

            String osname=System.getProperty("os.name");
            String filePath="";

            URL url = new URL("http://10.162.26.8/openLypsaa/reports/report_oc/127.0.0.1_sys_ANN_milkbill");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            if("Linux".equals(osname))
            {
                filePath = "/tmp/OLFile";
            }
            else
            {
                filePath = "C:/WINDOWS/Temp/OLFile";

            }

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                System.out.println(bytesRead);
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output.close();

    if("Linux".equals(osname))
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lp /tmp/OLFile").waitFor();
            else
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("print C:/WINDOWS/Temp/OLFile").waitFor();
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you would like to use: `filePath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\OLFile";`

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("print C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\OLFile").waitFor();
```

You can also google about `PathSeparator`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use java printing service which can be use on every platform. this code snippet send your print to your default printer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                
    FileInputStream textStream;
    try 
    {
        textStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\email_addresses.txt");
        DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(textStream, myFormat, null); 

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 

        aset.add(new Copies(1)); 
        aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED); 

        PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        System.out.println("Printing to default printer: " + printService.getName());

        DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();
        job.print(myDoc, aset);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```