# Java Sticker Printing Format Program

Tags: java, file, printing, position

Hi All
I have a requirement to print details on a sticker as per desired format.
Image attached for the same.
I have to print the details in column 2 of each row. The details must be printed at a particular position only. Its mandate to ensure uniformity.
The input in columns R1C2 , R2C2 will be given input to a program.
I had the logic framed that i can calculate x,y co-ordinates from where the print will start.
 The solution that i have in mind is to get the desired inputs to the program and write a text file. 
Then user prints the text file and gives the sticker as input to the printer. 
 The program can then print to the desired co-ordinates.
But i am unable to move to the particular position in Java. Can anyone please suggest if this can be accomplished in Java ? If yes, how ? 
 Let me know if further inputs are required here.
[image: Sticker Description]

[image: Sample Sticker]

Comment: I assume you're aware StackOverflow questions should show some attempt at code that needs fixing?
EDIT: If you want a gotoxy() in Java, and you're only concerned about console output, the escape character you want is 0x1B. Show me some code, and I'll help...

Comment: To print in java please have a look into the following url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586926/text-file-printing-java-applet-not-working-in-windows-os/19587149#19587149

Comment: @Dave, Thanks for the inputs. I am aware of the code attempt to be posted. However, I am still analyzing whether it will be possible in java. Will write code when i am convinced to a certain extent that the solution is going to work. I have to write the content to the file which can print it to a sticker. Primary concern is how to write content in a file at specified co-ordinates.

Comment: Files inherently do not contain co-ordinates that would be interpreted by a printer, unless you have a particular format for such file. Feel free to describe (or better yet, provide a link to) your printers acceptable format.

Comment: @Dave , uploaded sample sticker uploaded in post; if it helps.

Comment: I think you're slightly missing the point. The printer will have a specific format that you need to obey in order to pass it instructions. See a similar question re print positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505070/printing-reciepts-with-thermal-printer-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @Dave; thanks for sharing. Though the formatting is being done using tabs and new lines; still worth giving a try. Thanks again.

Comment: Then surely, you simply need an algorithm that will take inputs for the contents of stickers, parse that, and produce a String with `\t` and `\n` in appropriate places?

Comment: Yes, space , \t and \n will help me with the formatting but it will certainly not be a accurate measurement scale. But i am gonna try with it. Will share updates soon.